# Why is there no scheduled cached thread pool provided by the Java Executors class?

Tags: java, concurrency

`Executors` provides `newCachedThreadPool()` and `newScheduledThreadPool()`, but not `newCachedScheduledThreadPool()`, what gives here?  I have an application that receives bursty messages and needs to schedule a fairly lengthy processing step after a fixed delay for each.  The time constraints aren't super tight, but I would prefer to have more threads created on the fly if I exceed the pool size and then have them trimmed back during periods of inactivity.  Is there something I've missed in the concurrent library, or do I need to write my own?

Answer (score 10):

By design the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor is a fixed size. You can use a single threaded version that submits to a normal  ExecutorService for performing the task. This event thread + worker pool is fairly ease to coordinate and the flexibility makes up for the dedicated thread. I've used this in the past to replace TimerTasks and other non-critical tasks to utilize a common executor as a system-wide pool.

Answer (score 9):

Suggested here [Why does ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor only accept a fixed number of threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353002/why-does-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-only-accept-a-fixed-number-of-threads) workaround:

```
scheduledExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(128); //no more than 128 threads
scheduledExecutor.setKeepAliveTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
scheduledExecutor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
```

Comment: **Caution using this workaround**: consider this from the [documentation of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html): _"Additionally, it is almost never a good idea to set corePoolSize to zero or use **allowCoreThreadTimeOut** because this may leave the pool without threads to handle tasks once they become eligible to run."_

Comment: After poking around with this, I could not get the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to exhibit this behaviour. With the default implementation, if the thread pool is empty, `ensurePrestart()`, a private method called by all schedule methods, will create a worker to handle the new task. A github gist: https://gist.github.com/Groostav/600edf739a39cbbb33cbd64ad385d621

Comment: read: this implies that the comment @rmoestl is referencing is erroneous, and that GKislin's strategy is sound. It is still of course very concerning that the docs suggest this isn't a valid strategy, and its entirely possible that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.concurrent.Executors` is nothing more than a collection of static convenience methods that construct common arrangements of executors.

If you want something specific that isn't offered by `Executors`, then feel free to construct your own instance of the implemention classes, using the examples in `Executors` as a guide.

Comment: Imho this answer is misleading for the stated problem as it suggests that one can simply construct an Executor that meets this particular requirements. But reading the documentation of [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) indicates that calling several tuning methods inherited from [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) "have no useful effect" and thus the desired behaviour seems to be unsupported by `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score -3):

Like skaffman says, `Executors` is only a collection of factory method. if you need a particular instance, you can always check all existing `Executor` implementors. In your case, i think that calling one of the various constructors of [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) would be a good idea.

Comment: ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor has a fixed threadpool size though.