# Why does ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor only accept a fixed number of threads?

Tags: java, threadpool

I may imagine some tasks scheduled to take a very long time and `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` would create additional threads for the other tasks that need to be run, until a maximum number of threads is reached.

But seems that I can only specify a fixed number of threads for the pool, why is that so ?

Answer (score 11):

As the why, I don't know either. But I can imagine.

The amount of resources of a computer is limited. Not all resources can be handled concurrently either.

If multiple processes concurrently load files, they will be loaded slower than if they were being loaded sequentially (at least on a harddisk).

A processor also has limited support for handling multiple threads concurrently. At some point the OS or JVM will spend more time switching threads, than threads spend executing their code.

That is a good reason for the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to be designed the way it is. You can put any amount of jobs on the queue, but there are never executed more jobs at the same time than can be run efficiently. It's up to you to balance that, of course.

If your tasks are IO bound, I'd set the pool size small, and if they are CPU bound, a bit larger (32 or so). You can also make multiple `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`s, one for IO bound tasks and one for CPU bound tasks.

Comment: It depends on kind of I/O bound tasks - if you query a cloud service (lot of servers behind load balancer) with slow response then you can have 100s of threads. If your I/O bound tasks access HDD, then (probably) it is better to have few threads to give other tasks a change to use it too.

Answer (score 7):

While digging further about SchecduledThreadPoolExecutor I found this [link](http://book.javanb.com/java-threads-3rd/jthreads3-CHP-11-SECT-4.html), This link explains SchecduledThreadPoolExecutor solves many problems of Timer class. And also reason for introducing SchecduledThreadPoolExecutor was to replace Timer (due to various problems with Timer).
I think Reason for fixed number of threads passed to SchecduledThreadPoolExecutor is in one of problems this class solves. i.e.

> The Timer class starts only one
>   thread. While it is more efficient
>   than creating a thread per task, it is
>   not an optimal solution. The optimal
>   solution may be to use a number of
>   threads between one thread for all
>   tasks and one thread per task. In
>   effect, the best solution is to place
>   the tasks in a pool of threads. The
>   number of threads in the pool should
>   be assignable during construction to
>   allow the program to determine the
>   optimal number of threads in the pool.

So in my opinion this is where use case for SchecduledThreadPoolExecutor is coming from. In your case, You should be able to decide optimal value depending upon tasks you plan to schedule and time these tasks takes to finish. If I have 4 long running tasks which are scheduled for same time I would prefer my pool size be greater than 4 if there are other tasks to be executed during same time. I would also prefer to seperate out long running tasks in different executor as indicated in earlier answers.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

According to [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) there are the following disadvantages of unbounded thread creation:

**Thread lifecyle overhead**

Thread creation and teardown are not free. Thread creation takes time, and requires some processing activity by the JVM and OS.

**Resource consumption**

Active threads consume system resources, especially memory. When there are more runnable threads than available processors, threads sit idle. Having many idle threads can tie up a lot of memory, putting pressure on the garbage collector, and having many threads competing for the CPUs can impose other performance costs as well. If you have enough threads to keep all the CPUs busy, creating more threads won't help and may even hurt.

**Stability**

There is a limit on how many threads can be created. The limit varies by platform and is affected by factors including JVM invocation parameters, the requested stack size in the Thread constructor, and limits on threads placed by the underlying operating system. When you hit htis limit, the most likely result is an OutOfMemoryError. Trying to recover from such an error is very risky; it is far easier to structur your program to avoid hitting this limit.

---

Up to a certain point, more threads can improve throughput, but beyond that point creating more threads just slows down your application, and creating one thread too many can cause your entire application to crash horribly. The way to stay out of danger is to place some bound on how many threads your application creates, and to test your application thoroughly to ensure that, even when this bound is reached, it does not run out of resources.

Unbounded thread creation may appear to work just fine during prototyping and development, with problems surfacing only when the application is deployed and under heavy load.

Comment: Ok, these are some good advice in that book but having capability to set corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize don't violate these advice essentially because we can tune these sizes. So if you're right, What you can say about ThreadPoolExecutor which is parent of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and also supports maximumPoolSize?