# How to use virtual threads with ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I want to use virtual threads introduced in Java 19 and ScheduledExecutorService.
I need to schedule some threads to be run every minute. I know that I can use something like this: `ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100, Thread.ofVirtual().factory());` But it looks like I'm forced to set pool size.

I'm looking for a fabric method similar to this: `ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Thread.ofVirtual().factory());`
But I can't find it. I would like to follow "one virtual thread per task" principle and not be forced to set a fixed number of threads in the pool.
Do you know if I can use ScheduledExecutorService in that way? Or some alternative exists which are adapted to virtual threads?

**UPDATE**

Let me elaborate on what problem I try to solve.
So I need to create more than 1000 tasks (I don't know the exact number, I can only estimate it). Which should be run periodically. Some need to be run every minute, some every two minutes, etc.

Those tasks will perform I/O operations (network requests). So virtual threads look like a good choice.
But I need some scheduling functionality to achieve it.
By choosing ScheduledExecutorService I can use methods like:
`scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableTask, 60, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS )`

If I would not need scheduling I would simply create an executor like that: `var executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()`
But plain ExecutorService doesn't provide any scheduling functionality.
And I would be forced to implement scheduling on my own.

So for now the best solution I found is: `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1000, Thread.ofVirtual().factory());`
This generally looks good but I wonder if some other solution in Java API exists which allows me to create ScheduledExecutor but I will not be forced to set the size of a thread pool. Which for me looks a little bit strange when we consider virtual threads.

Comment: will the `Executors.cachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory threadFactory)` do? "Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available, and uses the provided ThreadFactory to create new threads when needed."

Comment: yes, but I need scheduling functionality so I would like to use methods like `scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()` which ScheduledExecutorService offer and plain Executor not.

Comment: Well there are [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3353002/16034206) as to why scheduledExecutorService is designed the way it is, you would be better off using a cachedThreadPool and writing logic to handle the scheduling yourself.

Comment: Don't conflate threads with _tasks._ A thread is an entity that _does_ things. A task is a thing that needs to be done. One does not submit threads to an executor service. One submits tasks. The executor service then usually (but not necessarily always) uses its _own_ thread(s) to perform the given tasks.

Comment: Re, "I would like to follow "one virtual thread per task" principle." That's great if you are creating the virtual threads yourself. But if you're going to use a _scheduled\*_ executor service, then why not trust it to do what's best? The people who write and maintain the JRE generally put a lot of thought into doing what's best.

Comment: \* If you were using a non-scheduled executor, then you might consider that the whole point of virtual threads is to eliminate the _need_ for thread pools. Using a non-scheduled executor (i.e., a thread pool) adds complexity to your program, but it solves a problem, namely, that creating and destroying threads is expensive. But creating and destroying _virtual_ threads is _not_ expensive. So, if you have virtual threads, then why add the complexity of a thread pool?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I updated the question. I described what problem exactly I try to solve. 
But for now, It looks like:
`ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100, Thread.ofVirtual().factory());` is the best choice for this kind of problem

Comment: @Piotrold, do not use it. It is not correct. Scheduled executor pools the thread internally. Virtual threads should not be pooled. So.. the accepted answer is the best solution as of now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want to consider offloading the work to virtual threads, and schedule the work with a sheduler.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
ExecutorService donkey = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()
```

Then when you want to schedule a task.

```
void schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit){
    scheduler.schedule( ()->donkey.execute(command), delay, unit);
}
```

You really don't want your scheduling thread to be split up amongst virtual threads because you want your scheduling thread to be free to schedule more tasks.

Comment: Just another excuse for the absence of standard API - ok men, change your applications that used scheduler for years (pattern established by JRE in 2004) just because ... why? What is wrong with that task queue (in the scheduler) being polled by virtual (not platform) thread? Sad but it what we have for LTS release...

Comment: @VladimirKonkov I fully agree with you. This is the best that I found so far but still, it looks more like a workaround,  then the actual solution for the problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0, Thread.ofVirtual().factory());
```

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I think everyone is overthinking this. The main benefit of Virtual Threads is the ability to spin up one virtual thread per task, and implement the task using synchronous APIs. Here is how I would implement this:

```
Thread.ofVirtual().start(() ->
{
  Thread.sleep(...); // Sleep until you want the task to run
  task.run();
  // Tada!
});
```

ScheduledExecutorService is a thread pool. You are not supposed to use thread pools with virtual threads.

Comment: Original question not about thread poll, actually. It is about Scheduled executor. Please show your solution for scheduled tasks.

Comment: @VladimirKonkov My answer already addresses this. If you want to schedule a task to run in X milliseconds, you spin up a thread, sleep X milliseconds and run the task.

Comment: [Virtual threads are short-lived and have shallow call stacks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/core/virtual-threads.html#GUID-4A63E9EA-B16A-4633-87D8-C3DC08A3277C). I would not put it to sleep and keep it running.

Comment: @HariR While it is true that most virtual threads are short-lived, I don't see this as a hard requirement. You can spin up over a million virtual threads and they are specifically designed for blocking operations.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement the VirtualScheduledExecutorService on your own.

```kotlin
/**
 *  Scheduler which uses JVM Scheduler to schedule jobs
 *
 * */
@BlockingExecutor
class LoomScheduledExecutorService internal constructor(
    private val actualImp: ExecutorService,
    private val timeSource: TimeSource.WithComparableMarks,
): AbstractExecutorService(), ScheduledExecutorService, Closeable {
//    val source: InstantSource = Clock.systemUTC()


    constructor(
        builder: Thread.Builder.OfVirtual = Thread.ofVirtual().name("virtual-dispatcher",0),
        timeSource: TimeSource.WithComparableMarks = TimeSource.Monotonic
    ):this(Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(builder.factory()), timeSource)

    private val sequencer = AtomicLong()

    override fun execute(command: java.lang.Runnable) =
        actualImp.execute(command)

    override fun shutdown() =
        actualImp.shutdown()

    override fun awaitTermination(timeout: Long, unit: TimeUnit) =
        actualImp.awaitTermination(timeout, unit)

    override fun isShutdown() = actualImp.isShutdown

    override fun isTerminated() = actualImp.isTerminated

    override fun shutdownNow() = actualImp.shutdownNow()

    override fun schedule(
        command: Runnable,
        delay: Long,
        unit: TimeUnit
    ): ScheduledFuture<*> {
//        val ins = source.instant()
        val duration = delay.toDuration(unit.toDurationUnit())
        val mark = timeSource.markNow() + duration
        val task = DelayedTask(
            command,
            Unit,
            mark,
            sequencer.getAndIncrement()
        )

        execute(task)
        return task
    }

    override fun <V : Any?> schedule(callable: Callable<V>, delay: Long, unit: TimeUnit): ScheduledFuture<V> {
        val duration = delay.toDuration(unit.toDurationUnit())
        val task = DelayedTask(
            callable,
            timeSource.markNow() + duration,
            sequencer.getAndIncrement()
        )
        execute(task)
        return task
    }

    override fun scheduleAtFixedRate(
        command: Runnable,
        initialDelay: Long,
        period: Long,
        unit: TimeUnit
    ): ScheduledFuture<*> {
        /**
         *
         * initialDelay,
         * then initialDelay + period,
         * then initialDelay + 2 * period
         * */
        val taskPeriod = period.toDuration(unit.toDurationUnit())
        if (taskPeriod <= Duration.ZERO) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("period <= 0")
        }

        val mark = timeSource.markNow() +
                initialDelay
                    .toDuration(unit.toDurationUnit())
        val task = FixedRateTask(command, Unit, mark, taskPeriod, sequencer.getAndIncrement())
        execute(task)
        return task
    }

    override fun scheduleWithFixedDelay(
        command: Runnable,
        initialDelay: Long,
        delay: Long,
        unit: TimeUnit
    ): ScheduledFuture<*> {
        /**
         *  initial delay,
         *  and subsequently
         *  with the given delay between
         *  the termination of one execution
         *  and the commencement of the next.
         * */

        val taskPeriod = delay.toDuration(unit.toDurationUnit())
        if (taskPeriod <= Duration.ZERO) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("period <= 0")
        }
        val mark = timeSource.markNow() +
                initialDelay
                    .toDuration(unit.toDurationUnit())
        val task = PeriodicTask(command, Unit, mark, taskPeriod, sequencer.getAndIncrement())
        execute(task)
        return task
    }

    override fun close() = super<AbstractExecutorService>.close()

    private data class Sleeping(
        private val expectedMark: ComparableTimeMark
    ): Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            Thread.sleep(expectedMark.elapsedNow().unaryMinus().toJavaDuration())
        }
    }


    private class RepeatableFutureTask<V>:FutureTask<V> {
        constructor(r: Runnable, result:V):super(r,result)
        constructor(c:Callable<V>):super(c)

        public override fun runAndReset(): Boolean {
            return super.runAndReset()
        }
    }

    sealed class BaseTask<V>: FutureTask<V>, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> {
        val mark: ComparableTimeMark
        val sequenceNumber:Long
        constructor(
            r:Runnable,
            result: V,
            sequenceNumber:Long,
            mark: ComparableTimeMark
        ): super(r, result) {
            this.sequenceNumber = sequenceNumber
            this.mark = mark

        }

        constructor(
            c: Callable<V>,
            sequenceNumber:Long,
            mark: ComparableTimeMark
        ): super(c) {
            this.sequenceNumber = sequenceNumber
            this.mark = mark
        }

        override fun isPeriodic() = false

        override fun compareTo(other: Delayed): Int {
            if (other == this) {
                return 0;
            }
            return if (other is BaseTask<*>) {
                if (other.expectedMark > expectedMark || other.expectedMark < expectedMark) {
                    expectedMark.compareTo(other.expectedMark)
                } else {
                    sequenceNumber.compareTo(other.sequenceNumber)
                }
            } else {
                val diff = getDelay(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) - other.getDelay(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
                if (diff < 0) -1 else if (diff > 0) 1 else 0
            }
        }

        override fun getDelay(unit: TimeUnit): Long {
            return expectedMark.elapsedNow().unaryMinus()
                .toLong(unit.toDurationUnit())
        }

        open val expectedMark:ComparableTimeMark
            get() = mark
    }

    private class DelayedTask<V> : BaseTask<V> {

        constructor(
            r:Runnable,
            result: V,
            triggerTime: ComparableTimeMark,
            sequenceNumber:Long
        ): super(r, result, sequenceNumber, triggerTime)

        constructor(
            c: Callable<V>,
            triggerTime: ComparableTimeMark,
            sequenceNumber:Long
        ): super(c, sequenceNumber, triggerTime)


        override fun isPeriodic() = false

        private val childTask = FutureTask(Sleeping(mark), Unit)

        override fun run() {
            childTask.run()
            if (childTask.isCancelled) {
                super.cancel(false)
            }
            super.run()
        }

        override fun cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning: Boolean): Boolean {
            childTask.cancel(true)
            return super.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)
        }

    }

    private class FixedRateTask<V>: BaseTask<V> {
        private val period: Duration

        @Volatile
        private var virtualMark:ComparableTimeMark
        private val initialDelay = FutureTask(Sleeping(mark), Unit)
        private val delayTask:RepeatableFutureTask<Unit>

        constructor(
            r:Runnable,
            result: V,
            triggerTime: ComparableTimeMark,
            period: Duration,
            sequenceNumber:Long
        ): super(r, result, sequenceNumber, triggerTime) {
            this.period = period
            this.virtualMark = mark
            val job = Runnable { Thread.sleep(virtualMark.elapsedNow().unaryMinus().toJavaDuration()) }
            this.delayTask = RepeatableFutureTask(job,Unit)
        }

        constructor(
            c: Callable<V>,
            triggerTime: ComparableTimeMark,
            period: Duration,
            sequenceNumber:Long
        ): super(c, sequenceNumber, triggerTime) {
            this.period = period
            this.virtualMark = mark
            val job = Runnable { Thread.sleep(virtualMark.elapsedNow().unaryMinus().toJavaDuration()) }
            this.delayTask = RepeatableFutureTask(job,Unit)
        }

        override fun run() {
            initialDelay.run()
            if (initialDelay.isCancelled) {
                super.cancel(false)
                delayTask.cancel(false)
            }
            var before = mark + mark.elapsedNow()
            while (runAndReset()) {

                val after = mark + mark.elapsedNow()
                val workDuration = after - before
//                before = after
                if (workDuration < period) {
                    virtualMark = after + (period - workDuration)
                    if (!delayTask.runAndReset()) {
                        cancel(false)
                        break
                    }
                } else {
                    // run job ASAP
                    virtualMark = after
                }
                before = mark + mark.elapsedNow()

            }
        }

        override fun isPeriodic() = true

        override val expectedMark get() = virtualMark

        override fun cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning: Boolean): Boolean {
            initialDelay.cancel(true)
            delayTask.cancel(true)
            return super.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)
        }
    }

    private class PeriodicTask<V>: BaseTask<V> {
        private val period: Duration

        private var virtualMark:ComparableTimeMark
        constructor(
            r:Runnable,
            result: V,
            triggerTime: ComparableTimeMark,
            period: Duration,
            sequenceNumber:Long
        ): super(r, result, sequenceNumber, triggerTime) {
            this.period = period
            this.virtualMark = mark
            this.delayTask = RepeatableFutureTask(Sleep(period),Unit)
        }

        constructor(
            c: Callable<V>,
            triggerTime: ComparableTimeMark,
            period: Duration,
            sequenceNumber:Long
        ): super(c, sequenceNumber, triggerTime) {
            this.period = period
            this.virtualMark = mark
            this.delayTask = RepeatableFutureTask(Sleep(period),Unit)
        }

        private val initialDelay = FutureTask(Sleeping(mark), Unit)
        private val delayTask:RepeatableFutureTask<Unit>

        private data class Sleep(private val duration: Duration):Runnable {

            override fun run() {
                Thread.sleep(duration.toJavaDuration())
            }
        }

        override fun run() {
            initialDelay.run()
            if (initialDelay.isCancelled) {
                super.cancel(false)
                delayTask.cancel(false)
            }
            while (runAndReset()) {
                virtualMark = mark + mark.elapsedNow() + period
                if (!delayTask.runAndReset()) {
                    cancel(false)
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        override fun isPeriodic() = true

        override val expectedMark get() = virtualMark

        override fun cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning: Boolean): Boolean {
            initialDelay.cancel(true)
            delayTask.cancel(true)
            return super.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)
        }
    }

}
```